# cluster over sparse matrix

Tags: python, cluster-computing, sparse-matrix, similarity

I am newbie in learning data analysis by using python.

I have a question about how to classify or clustering on a sparse matrix.I have a sparse matrix like this:

```
        A   B   C   D   E   
day1    0   0   1   0   1   
day2    0   1   0   0   0   
day3    0   0   1   0   1   
day4    0   0   1   1   0   
day5    1   0   0   1   1   
day6    1   0   0   0   1   
day7    0   1   1   0   0   
day8    1   1   0   1   1   
day9    1   0   0   0   1   
day10   0   0   1   0   0
```

each column represents a job run by this day and I want to calculate the similarity between the days in order to assign each day into a cluster.

I expect my output looks like this:

```
        A   B   C   D   E   Group
day1    0   0   1   0   1   1
day2    0   1   0   0   0   2
day3    0   0   1   0   1   1
day4    0   0   1   1   0   1
day5    1   0   0   1   1   3
day6    1   0   0   0   1   1
day7    0   1   1   0   0   1
day8    1   1   0   1   1   3
day9    1   0   0   0   1   1
day10   0   0   1   0   0   2
```

I don't know what the real cluster index should be like so I make it up.

Is there anyone tell me which algorithm or cluster method I should use to address the problem? I really appreciate for that!